# Preventing basic app information/developer information from being accessed by non-Apple users on apps currently in development

Tags: ios, xcode, security

Can someone hack or easily access the dev info/app info out of an iOS app not from the app store, such as those that are ad hoc or normal debug versions on provisioned devices. If so how could I make this preventable? For in-house apps in stealth mode with large testing pools I cannot let this info get out. Any information would be helpful.

Comment: Are you trying to hide things like class names or payload data like images, etc.?

Comment: The assets of the app are not a big deal, I just don't want someone who gets a hold of one of my tester's phones to be able to find out what group made the app or other basic data about the app like code-signing id, etc

Answer (score 1):

Aside from creating an entirely separate Apple developer account for this purpose you're going to find it nearly impossible to hide the data you want to hide. For $99 you can solve the whole problem.

Comment: the only issue is that Apple needs to verify all developer information, so I can't make a throwaway dev account not tied to my group that must stay undisclosed... right?

Comment: If you're not *selling* the app with this developer account then you don't have to submit all the banking, etc. info that is required for store contracts. You could just build a throwaway email that you destroy later.

Comment: Gotcha Jeff. I guess you have a point there. You win!

Comment: I'll mark you as the answer if this account gets enough points to do so

Comment: @ExcellentToEachOther, you don't need points to accept an answer (the check mark).